# Python regex: Bad character range

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the next regular expression to find emojis on a text:

```
re.compile(u'([\U00002600-\U000027BF])|([\U0001F300-\U0001F64F])|([\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF])')
```

It is working well in Python 3 but in Python 2.7 I get this:

```
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

How can I fix it to support both, Python 2.7 and Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

Use `r'(...` instead of `u'(...`  like this:

```
re.compile(r'([\U00002600-\U000027BF\U0001F300-\U0001F64F\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF])')
```

Also note that you can specify multiple ranges inside `[...]`

https://regex101.com/r/WuQ3Zr/1

Comment: It's interesting. I tried your solution in interactive mode and it works but when I execute the program or when I run pytest, it fails. What could be the cause?

Comment: Which version of Python failed?

Comment: The interpreter is Python 2.7.0 and that code inside a file run by python <file> works ok. It's only in my system when running the cli or running pytest locally. This is the code https://github.com/davidmogar/cucco/tree/executable and this is the build in Travis https://travis-ci.org/davidmogar/cucco/builds/238482411 Do you think that is only a problem with my system or this could happen to others? I'm running it on a Macbook.

Comment: Just tried again in a virtual environment with 3.6.0 and still fails in local. The build for 3.6.0 in Travis works.