# What is efficient way to check if current word is close to a word in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pattern-matching, stop-words

consider examples below :

1. Example 1 :

   ```
   str1 = "wow...it  looks amazing"
   str2 = "looks amazi"
   ```

   You see that `amazi` is close to `amazing`, `str2` is mistyped, i wanted to write a program that will tell me that `amazi` is close to `amazing` then in `str2` i will replace `amazi` with `amazing`
2. Example 2 :

   ```
   str1 = "is looking good"
   str2 = "looks goo"
   ```

   In this case updated `str2` will be `"looking good"`
3. Example 3 :

   ```
   str1 = "you are really looking good"
   str2 = "lok goo"
   ```

   In this case `str2` will be `"good"` as `lok` is not close to `looking` (or even if program can convert in this case `lok` to `looking` then it's just fine for my  problem's solution)
4. Example 4 :

   ```
   str1 = "Stu is actually SEVERLY sunburnt....it hurts!!!"
   str2 = "hurts!!"
   ```

   Updated `str2` will be `"hurts!!!"`
5. Example 5 :

   ```
   str1 = "you guys were absolutely amazing tonight, a..."
   str2 = "ly amazin"
   ```

   Updated `str2` will be `"amazing"`, `"ly"` shall be removed or replace by absolutely.

What will be the  algo and  code for this?

Maybe we can do it by looking at character lexicographically and set a
threshold like 0.8 or 80% so if `word2` gets 80% sequential characters of `word1` from `str1` then we replace `word2` in `str2` with word of `str1`?
Any other efficient solution with python code please?

Comment: The python package https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/ may be what you are looking for.

Comment: You should use a bayesian network for this task since finding the correct world is a question of probabilities

Comment: that package shows the ratio? i wanted to check where we have a word that is very close but not exactly same,at that point just simply replace with original word,,can you post your solution code as answer? i will accept if it passes all test case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to approach this.  This one solves all of your examples.  I added a minimum similarity filter to return only the higher quality matches.  This is what allows the 'ly' to be dropped in the last sample, as it is not all that close any any of the words.

[Documentation](https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html)

You can install levenshtein with `pip install python-Levenshtein`

```
import Levenshtein

def find_match(str1,str2):
    min_similarity = .75
    output = []
    results = [[Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(x,y) for x in str1.split()] for y in str2.split()]
    for x in results:
        if max(x) >= min_similarity:
            output.append(str1.split()[x.index(max(x))])
    return output
```

Each sample you proposed.

```
find_match("is looking good", "looks goo")

['looking','good']

find_match("you are really looking good", "lok goo")

['looking','good']

find_match("Stu is actually SEVERLY sunburnt....it hurts!!!", "hurts!!")

['hurts!!!']

find_match("you guys were absolutely amazing tonight, a...", "ly amazin")

['amazing']
```

Comment: greatest answer,,passes every test case,,upvoted and accepted,,can't ask for any better answer than this

Comment: 1 additional question : is it possible to use your python-Levenshtein code offline? this code won't work  without internet

Comment: This code should not require an internet connection.  If it's failing it's likely due to something else

Comment: pip install python-Levenshtein are we not using internet for this installation?

Comment: Oh yes for the package but that's one time. You could download the package to a thumb drive and install from there once on site. Or install it on one machine and copy that python folder to a thumb drive to install elsewhere. Plenty of ways to handle getting pip packages without a connection.

Comment: thank you,one last question if you don't mind,,is there any way to make string 2 spelling correction by looking at english dictionary instead of str1? i mean str2 has amazi which is close to amazing right? i would like to know how can i update this code so it looks the best match from english dictionary then replaces? it would be much better for my nlp project,just asking for a friend,thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
str1 = "wow...it looks amazing"
str2 =  "looks amazi"
str3 = []

# Checking for similar strings in both strings:
for n in str1.split():
    for m in str2.split():
        if m in n:
            str3.append(n)

# If found 2 similar strings:
if len(str3) == 2:
    # If their indexes align:
    if str1.split().index(str3[1]) - str1.split().index(str3[0]) == 1:
        print(' '.join(str3))

elif len(str3) == 1:
    print(str3[0])
```

Output:

```
looks amazing
```

UPDATE with condition given by the OP:

```
str1 = "good..."
str2 =  "god.."
str3 = []

# Checking for similar strings in both strings:
for n in str1.split():
    for m in str2.split():

        # Calculating matching character in the 2 words:
        c = ''
        for i in m:
            if i in n:
                c+=i
        # If the amount of matching characters is greater or equal to 50% the length of the larger word
        # or the smaller word is in the larger word:
        if len(list(c)) >= len(n)*0.50 or m in n:
            str3.append(n)


# If found 2 similar strings:
if len(str3) == 2:
    # If their indexes align:
    if str1.split().index(str3[1]) - str1.split().index(str3[0]) == 1:
        print(' '.join(str3))

elif len(str3) == 1:
    print(str3[0])
```

Comment: i am trying different strings with your code,,but your code is awesome,not sure why and who downvoted it

Comment: str1 = "wow...it looks amazing"
str2 =  "loks amazi" here loks is close to looks so it should give me looks amazing but your program gives "amazing"

Comment: You need to give a rule as to what means similar. Computers don't have senses, so they need rules. For example, a rule that tells the computer that two words are similar if both share 5 same letters.

Comment: is it possible to do with some threshold by checking how many character match we have?

Comment: @MobassirHossen  Yes, it is. Can you give one?

Comment: consider looks vs loks...looks has 5 characters and loks has 4 characters,,,and 4 of these loks characters in  5 of those looks characters,,so we can do what percentage characters are matching and then say like if that percentage is >80% then we replace otherwise we don't

Comment: According to your example, the percentage should be >= 75%.

Comment: not sure why 2 downvotes,,the  code works fine for me,,accepted and upvoted,thank you

Comment: Thanks. I have been targeted by a serial downvoter from yesterday to today :(  I posted on meta

Comment: str1 = "good..."
str2 =  "good.."
str3 = []  sorry it is not working with updated code  now

Comment: str1 should be longer than str2

Comment: your first code solves this issue str1 = "good..."
str2 =  "good.."
str3 = [] but updated code not working for it

Comment: Hold on, I'll check

Comment: Corrected it, c should have been a string, not a set :)

Comment: another bug found,,it gives good... for this str1 = "good..."
str2 =  "doog"
str3 = []  any suggestion for this? doog and good are not same,,can we apply any rule for such cases?

Comment: I don't understand, I just tried it and it worked. Can you copy and paste mine and try again?

Comment: That's because in my program, since all character of do is in good, that gives 100%. Can you give the threshold more details?

Comment: i am less experience than you,so if you could give a better threshold idea to handle as much as such worst case scenario possible then it would be highly appreciated

Comment: Okay, give me some time ;)

Answer (score 1):

I made through it with regular expressions

```
def check_regex(str1,str2):
    #New list to store the updated value
    str_new = []
    for i in str2:
        # regular expression for comparing the strings
        x = ['['+i+']','^'+i,i+'$','('+i+')']
        for k in x:
            h=0
            for j in str1:
                #Conditions to make sure the word is close enough to the particular word
                if "".join(re.findall(k,j)) == i or ("".join(re.findall(k,j)) in i and abs(len("".join(re.findall(k,j)))-len(i)) == 1 and len(i)!=2):
                    str_new.append(j)
                    h=1
                    break
            if h==1:
                break
    return str_new
import re
str1 = input().split()
str2 = input().split()
print(" ".join(check_regex(str1,str2)))
```

[image: see for me it's running]

Comment: probably this code is wrong,,i got g g g g for str1 = "good..."
str2 =  "goog"

Comment: will you please give the full sentence for str1 because when i run it gives me good...

Comment: this is also an example : str1 = "good..."
str2 =  "goog" for what your program failed

Comment: I have added a picture that shows that it runs for me with the same code i mentioned

Comment: thank you,it works,,,consider this example : str1 = "looking.."
str2 =  "lok" for this code of chris outputs str1 but your regex outputting nothing but for other cases it works just fine,thanks

Comment: because lok is not close to looking as mentioned by you in your question

Comment: today i got this error with your regex : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314290/python-regex-bad-character-range

Comment: str1 = ['yeah,', 'when', 'you', 'start', 'reaching', 'your', 'early-mid-20s']
str2 = ['early-mid-20s']
 that causes this error

Comment: seems like there are more bugs in this code : 
str1 = "early-mid".split()
str2 = "early mid".split()
print(" ".join(check_magic(str1,str2)))

it prints "early-mid early-mid" twice

Answer (score -2):

You can use Jacard coefficient in this case. First, you need to split your first and second string by space. After that, for every string in str2, take Jacard coefficient with every string in str1, then replace with which that gives you the highest Jacard coefficient.

You can use `sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score`.

Comment: You edited your comment after I downvoted it.  That's why it was downvoted.

Comment: Ok, then are you satisfied with my answer now or not.